# recursive mergeflow max recursion exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to implement recursive mergeflow for an online class and have a small problem.

The code to divide and conquer works fine like this:

```
def __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, lo, hi):
    if hi <= lo:
        return
    mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2

    __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, lo, mid)
    __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, mid + 1, hi)
    # Call merge here...


def mergesort(x):
    aux = [0] * len(x)
    __recursive_mergesort(x, aux, 0, len(x) - 1)
    return x
```

However, when I do:

```
def __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, lo, hi):
    if hi <= lo:
        return
    mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2

    __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, lo, mid)
    __recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, mid, hi)
    # Call merge here...


def mergesort(x):
    aux = [0] * len(x)
    __recursive_mergesort(x, aux, 0, len(x))
    return x
```

This exceeds the maximum recursion depth. As far as I can tell, I have not changed the logic and I am having trouble debugging this. Of course there is a subtle or not so subtle bug lurking in here but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the first version runs and not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that your base-case:

```
if hi <= lo:
    return
```

Will never occur if your second recursive call doesn't add `1` to mid. Consider, we get to the point

```
hi = 1; lo = 0; mid = 0
```

So then our calculation for `mid` results in:

```
In [21]: hi = 1; lo = 0; mid = 0

In [22]: lo + (hi - lo) // 2
Out[22]: 0
```

Which you then pass to `__recursive_mergesort(arr, aux, mid, hi)` with the exact same values, so you will get infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks for that. I realized changing the condition to `    if hi - 1 <= lo:
        return` works...